# Future String in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

So I have a function that returns a value that is of future. When this function executes I want to extract the string from the future. How should I do this?

```
Future<String> coverImage(id, space) {
  String link = 'https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/$space/assets/$id?access_token=1d4932ce2b24458e85ded26532bb81184e0d79c1a16c5713ec3ad391c2e8f5b3';
  return http.get(link).then((response) => decodeToImage(decodeJson(response.body)));   
}
```

this function return `Future<String>`, i want to extract to string when i am using with image widget

Answer (score 28):

```
Future someMethod() async {
  String s = await someFuncThatReturnsFuture();
}
```

or

```
someMethod() {
  someFuncTahtReturnsFuture().then((s) {
    print(s);
  });
}
```

There is no way to go from async (Future) to sync execution.
`async`/`await` is only syntactic sugar to make the code look more like sync code, but as you see in my first example, `someMethod` will return a `Future` and if you want to use the string `s` on the call site, you have to use `async`/`await` or `then()` there.